# Run MapR script (Google Cloud SDK) to create MapR Hadoop cluster on GCP does not work

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, google-cloud-platform, mapr

I downloaded scripts from https://github.com/mapr/gce for run MapR script to create MapR Hadoop cluster on GCP.

I already credential Google account with GCP. `gcloud auth list` OK.

Run MapR script.

```
./launch-admin-training-cluster.sh --project stone-cathode-10xxxx --cluster MaprBank10 --config-file 4node_yarn.lst --image centos-6 --machine-type n1-standard-2 --persistent-disks 1x256
```

This's messages from Cygwin command line.

> CHECK: -----
>   project-id stone-cathode-10xxxx
>   cluster MaprBank10
>   config-file 4node_yarn.lst
>   image centos-6   machine n1-standard-2
>   zone us-central1-b
>
> OPTIONAL: -----
>     node-name none
>   persistent-disks 1x256
>
> ----- Proceed {y/N} ? y Launch node1
>
> Creating persistent data volumes first (1x256) seq: not found
>   Launch node2
>
> Creating persistent data volumes first (1x256) seq: not found
>   Launch node3
>
> Creating persistent data volumes first (1x256) seq: not found
>   Launch node4
>
> Creating persistent data volumes first (1x256) seq: not found
>
> NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE PREEMPTIBLE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS

How to Investigate and solve issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The course ADM-201 has particular requirement that you must follow.
The config file that you have chosen is 4node_yarn.lst and it supports 3 x 50 persistent-disks for each node in your 4-node MapR cluster. Since you are mentioning only one disk (1 x 256) in your command, it is not able to meet it's requirements.

Also carefully follow the "Set Up a Virtual Cluster" provided by MapR. Below is the screenshot from the guide provided by MapR.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. My [document](https://training.mapr.com/sites/default/files/attachment/1437413895-Set%20Up%20a%20Virtual%20Cluster%20for%20Training.pdf) don't last updated . But I retry with this command. `./launch-admin-training-cluster.sh --project stone-cathode-1xxxxx --cluster Cluster1 --mapr-version 4.0.1 --config-file 4node_yarn.lst --image centos-6 --machine-type n1-standard-2 --persistent-disks 3x50 ` It's doesn't work. result same.

Comment: What are the steps that you followed? Did you follow step by step of mapr guide? Could you post the error output again?

Comment: Turn off Firewall & AntiVirus.

My Cygwin command http://paste.ofcode.org/3brZT6GFabnjkhVkVL7Burq

I hidden some personal information.